# Import cannot be resolved in eclispe project using maven

Tags: eclipse

Recently I kept hitting an issue of Eclipse not recognising my imports (even though they were there). I was always getting the message:

```
import ClassName cannot be resolved.
```

I am using maven to clean and build project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `Project` => check `Build automatically` and `Clean`.

If this doesn't solve the problem..

```
Right click the "Maven Dependencies" => "Build Path" => "Remove from the build path";
Right click the project, go to "Maven" => "Update project";
```

HTH